# Removing -,= or space reg ex

Tags: regex, notepad++

I have to remove any number of `-,=` or spaces after the word `text:` in my text file but before the tweet begins. So far I have this as an idea. `text: ,|-|=|` This accounts for more than one space but also deletes all spaces in the entire text file. Here are a few lines of the text for an example.

```
 posted: Sat Feb 03 2018 11:03:09   text: ,Today we can see positive trends for growth, but will there be a new fall? crypto screen_name: Ksandimo  location: null  verified: false followers_count: 1597   friends_count: 17   lang: ru    retweet_count: 0    favorite_count: 0
 posted: Sat Feb 03 2018 11:03:14   text: 8745.02$ per now  screen_name: CoinLibre2009  location: Free World    verified: false followers_count: 113    friends_count: 110  lang: ru    retweet_count: 0    favorite_count: 0
 posted: Sat Feb 03 2018 11:03:16   text: Current price of is $8745.02  screen_name: bitcoinavg location: null  verified: false followers_count: 44 friends_count: 9    lang: en    retweet_count: 0    favorite_count: 0
 posted: Sat Feb 03 2018 11:03:25   text: Think weve hit resistance for Bitcoin now. Will it fully recover? Im not sure screen_name: jasongaved location: Brighton & Hove / London  verified: false followers_count: 1996   friends_count: 1967 lang: en    retweet_count: 0    favorite_count: 0
 posted: Sat Feb 03 2018 11:03:28   text: Today's price is $8745.02 as of February 3, 2018 at 11:59AM   screen_name: FR33Q  location: Europe    verified: false followers_count: 1164   friends_count: 1998 lang: en    retweet_count: 0    favorite_count: 0
 posted: Sat Feb 03 2018 11:03:37   text: bitcoin might have been a hoax, the issue that the outrage was at these   screen_name: krrishd_pzombie    location: your mind verified: false followers_count: 28 friends_count: 12   lang: en    retweet_count: 0    favorite_count: 0
 posted: Sat Feb 03 2018 11:03:50   text:  =I believe the chart would be adoption of 'blockchain technology' rather than bitcoin individually...    screen_name: mt_crypto  location: null  verified: false followers_count: 34 friends_count: 90   lang: en    retweet_count: 0    favorite_count: 0
 posted: Sat Feb 03 2018 11:04:07   text: Current price of Bitcoin is $8745.02 via Chain    screen_name: kimrin location: Kawasaki  verified: false followers_count: 690    friends_count: 1012 lang: ja    retweet_count: 0    favorite_count: 0
 posted: Sat Feb 03 2018 11:04:14   text:  -Compensation?  Sounds interesting.   Like 1 Bitcoin perhaps? Maybe a couple of Ethereum.   Whatchu got in mind? screen_name: rahulsood  location: seattle washington    verified: true  followers_count: 38820  friends_count: 2224 lang: en    retweet_count: 0    favorite_count: 0
```

Sample output:

```
posted: Sat Feb 03 2018 11:03:09    text: Today we can see positive trends for growth, but will there be a new fall? crypto screen_name: Ksandimo   location: null  verified: false followers_count: 1597   friends_count: 17   lang: ru    retweet_count: 0    favorite_count: 0
posted: Sat Feb 03 2018 11:03:14    text: 8745.02$ per now  screen_name: CoinLibre2009  location: Free World    verified: false followers_count: 113    friends_count: 110  lang: ru    retweet_count: 0    favorite_count: 0
posted: Sat Feb 03 2018 11:03:16    text: Current price of is $8745.02  screen_name: bitcoinavg location: null  verified: false followers_count: 44 friends_count: 9    lang: en    retweet_count: 0    favorite_count: 0
posted: Sat Feb 03 2018 11:03:25    text: Think weve hit resistance for Bitcoin now. Will it fully recover? Im not sure screen_name: jasongaved location: Brighton & Hove / London  verified: false followers_count: 1996   friends_count: 1967 lang: en    retweet_count: 0    favorite_count: 0
posted: Sat Feb 03 2018 11:03:28    text: Today's price is $8745.02 as of February 3, 2018 at 11:59AM   screen_name: FR33Q  location: Europe    verified: false followers_count: 1164   friends_count: 1998 lang: en    retweet_count: 0    favorite_count: 0
posted: Sat Feb 03 2018 11:03:37    text: bitcoin might have been a hoax, the issue that the outrage was at these   screen_name: krrishd_pzombie    location: your mind verified: false followers_count: 28 friends_count: 12   lang: en    retweet_count: 0    favorite_count: 0
posted: Sat Feb 03 2018 11:03:50    text: I believe the chart would be adoption of 'blockchain technology' rather than bitcoin individually...  screen_name: mt_crypto  location: null  verified: false followers_count: 34 friends_count: 90   lang: en    retweet_count: 0    favorite_count: 0
```

Comment: hey should it delete those characters just after `text:`? and not those characters in the rest of the line?

Comment: @Allan there should be only one space after "text: ". Any character except any number of -,= or spaces have to be removed.

Comment: OK thanks have a check at my solution and let me know if it helps you or if you need some explanations

Comment: You should have shown us sample output as well.  We can't read your mind.  Not everyone at least.

Comment: @Brad in your sample o/p you have more than one white space e.g Free World    verified: false followe

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Find**: `text:\s+[,=\s-]*`

**Replace**: `text:` (with one space at the end)

**Improved solution:**

**Find**: `(?<=^posted:\s[A-Z][a-z]{2}\s[A-Z][a-z]{2}\s\d{2}\s\d{4}\s\d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2}\s{3})text:\s+[,=\s-]*`

**Replace**: `text:` (with one space at the end)

**[DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/D1EZog/1/)**

The improve solution will avoid that other occurrences of `text:\s+[,=\s-]*` appearing later on the line are converted to `text:`.

Comment: Good answer, the OP was totally unclear to me as to what it actually wanted.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen sorry about that.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen: sorry for that! I have actually edited my solution and made it way more restrictive just in case

Comment: FYI: Npp doesn't recognize look behind.

Answer (score 1):

This should do what you want.

```
text:[,|\-|=|\s]+
```

**\s** will match any whitespace

the **+** means match 1 or more of the preceding element. In this case it will match any whitespace or *-,=*

[Example](https://regexr.com/3lvmc)

Comment: Why are you using capture group? It slow down the regex. And how do you use this regex in Notepad++?

Comment: @Toto Usually I use capture groups to change based on the context of each individual match. But in this case you are correct. Probably more performant not to use it. Especially since notepad++ dosen't care about capture groups.

Answer (score 1):

- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd>
- Find what: `^.*?text:\h\K[-=,\h]+`
- Replace with: `LEAVE EMPTY`
- *check Wrap around*
- *check Regular expression*
- *DO NOT CHECK `. matches newline`*
- <kbd>Replace all</kbd>

**Explanation:**

```
^           : beginning of line
  .*?       : 0 or more any character not greedy
  text:     : literally "text:"
  \h        : 1 horizontal space
  \K        : forget all we have seen until this position
  [-=,\h]+  : 1 or more any of these character, dash, equal, comma or horizontal space
```

**Result for given example:**

```
 posted: Sat Feb 03 2018 11:03:09   text: Today we can see positive trends for growth, but will there be a new fall? crypto screen_name: Ksandimo  location: null  verified: false followers_count: 1597   friends_count: 17   lang: ru    retweet_count: 0    favorite_count: 0
 posted: Sat Feb 03 2018 11:03:14   text: 8745.02$ per now  screen_name: CoinLibre2009  location: Free World    verified: false followers_count: 113    friends_count: 110  lang: ru    retweet_count: 0    favorite_count: 0
 posted: Sat Feb 03 2018 11:03:16   text: Current price of is $8745.02  screen_name: bitcoinavg location: null  verified: false followers_count: 44 friends_count: 9    lang: en    retweet_count: 0    favorite_count: 0
 posted: Sat Feb 03 2018 11:03:25   text: Think weve hit resistance for Bitcoin now. Will it fully recover? Im not sure screen_name: jasongaved location: Brighton & Hove / London  verified: false followers_count: 1996   friends_count: 1967 lang: en    retweet_count: 0    favorite_count: 0
 posted: Sat Feb 03 2018 11:03:28   text: Today's price is $8745.02 as of February 3, 2018 at 11:59AM   screen_name: FR33Q  location: Europe    verified: false followers_count: 1164   friends_count: 1998 lang: en    retweet_count: 0    favorite_count: 0
 posted: Sat Feb 03 2018 11:03:37   text: bitcoin might have been a hoax, the issue that the outrage was at these   screen_name: krrishd_pzombie    location: your mind verified: false followers_count: 28 friends_count: 12   lang: en    retweet_count: 0    favorite_count: 0
 posted: Sat Feb 03 2018 11:03:50   text: I believe the chart would be adoption of 'blockchain technology' rather than bitcoin individually...    screen_name: mt_crypto  location: null  verified: false followers_count: 34 friends_count: 90   lang: en    retweet_count: 0    favorite_count: 0
 posted: Sat Feb 03 2018 11:04:07   text: Current price of Bitcoin is $8745.02 via Chain    screen_name: kimrin location: Kawasaki  verified: false followers_count: 690    friends_count: 1012 lang: ja    retweet_count: 0    favorite_count: 0
 posted: Sat Feb 03 2018 11:04:14   text: Compensation?  Sounds interesting.   Like 1 Bitcoin perhaps? Maybe a couple of Ethereum.   Whatchu got in mind? screen_name: rahulsood  location: seattle washington    verified: true  followers_count: 38820  friends_count: 2224 lang: en    retweet_count: 0    favorite_count: 0
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select regexp_replace(regexp_replace('posted: =   Sat Feb 03 2018 11:03:50       text:  =I believe - the chart      would = be adoption of','.*text:','')
,',|-|=|\\s{2,}','')
```

\s{2,} is for more than one space

Comment: OP wants to use Notepad++

Answer (score 0):

Try `replace(/,|-|  |=/g, '')`. If you want to further remove spaces reduce one space from regx.

Comment: OP wants to use Notepad++